# Why is GWT 2.5.1 missing from Maven repo?

Tags: java, maven, gwt, dependency-management

I just installed [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/) (the Maven Eclipse plugin) and created a new Maven Project with a Quickstart archetype. I then went to the [official Maven repo](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.google.gwt|gwt|2.5.1|pom) to pull down GWT 2.5.1's dependencies, and see that it wants you to add the following `<dependency>` element to your project's `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

So, altogether, my `pom.xml` looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me.myorg</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resolver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>maven-resolver</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am getting the following error:

> Missing artifact com.google.gwt:gwt:jar:2.5.1

And furthermore, in Eclipse's Package Explorer, under my project's **Maven Dependencies** library, nothing is resolving.

What's going on here? Thanks in advance!

**Update:** the contents of `~/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt/2.5.1` are as follows:

```
gwt-2.5.1.jar.lastUpdated  gwt-2.5.1.pom.sha1
gwt-2.5.1.pom              _maven.repositories
```

Comment: The problem is that you are referencing a jar artifact which does not exist in central only a pom. I'm not a gwt expert but i would assume you need other [dependencies](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.google.gwt%22)

Comment: update your project settings and force update on the online repository. This dependency it's OK and gwt depends only for the org.json lib

Comment: Thanks @DeividiCavarzan (+1) - how do I force update?

Comment: Right click on project > Maven > Update Project >. Select Force Update Snapshots/Releases

Comment: Thanks again but that still doesn't fix the error...

Comment: Is this jar present at the .m2 folder? try to see what are inside the user/.m2/com/google/gwt folder. if there is a pom but the jar ins't there, you can manually download the jar and put on this folder

Comment: Or even run the mvn clean -U install command

Comment: Thanks - please see my update for the answer to your 1st question; also I tried `mvn clean -U install` and nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gwt dependencie it's a parent pom for the gwt project. This means that the repo will only contain the hash and the pom, but not the jar.

You need to use two libraries: [gwt-servlet](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-servlet/2.5.1) and [gwt-user](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-user/2.5.1):

I've found this configuration for GWT development (maybe you don't need to put the `<scope>` as described):

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  <dependencies>
```

Remove your dependencies and update your pom with these two shown above.

You can also use the [gwt-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/index.html) to manage your gwt project and deploy via maven. I've found this information there.

I hope that works!